# Can passwords be longer than 79 characters in Centos/RHEL 7?

Tags: linux, security, centos, passwords, centos-7

Installing Centos 7, I discovered that `passwd` is limiting the length of user passwords when they are set, without informing the user, as per [this five-year-old bug report](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7927).

This means any password longer than 79 characters is being silently cropped without informing the user. To me, this is a serious and fundamental flaw in usability, security, and common sense.

Is there a way to work around this bug?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your primary question, I can confirm this bug still exists in CentOS 7. I do not have a solution regarding a work around.

I followed the steps to reproduce in the article you linked to and found the same results. As per the article I had to remove the A character at the end to get the password to validate. Tested in centos-release-7-5.1804.